# How can I block updates in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-update, windows-10

I'm trying to figure out how best to stop Windows 10 from helping itself to updates. Firstly, I have a metered connection to the internet, and one that is of inconsistent speed. Secondly, I have an ideological objection to Microsoft installing its software without my permission (I have been burned by this before).

I'm aware that there is a setting for metered connections that delays downloads of some updates, but that doesn't prevent the others from being downloaded.

I've also found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930), but it doesn't seem to block updates in general, rather just blacklists certain updates that have already come out, and that your computer may or may not have already automatically downloaded and installed already.

I understand that Microsoft has no intention of returning to the days when you could see a list of updates, screen them, then downloading them when you have data to spare. But, is there any way that I can stop Windows from updating at all, for extended periods of time, then re-enable updating once I have the data?

Is there, maybe, a nice lightweight firewall that could block Windows Update?

EDIT: I have enabled the "defer upgrades" option, as suggested by the first answerer of the question I'm supposedly duplicating, but as Windows informs me, it will still help itself to security updates. I'm looking for a way to perform a blanket block on all updates until I want to install them, even if it means whitelisting every program that I want to use the internet. Does anyone here know how I could go about this?

Comment: Simplest solution is upgrade to Windows 10 Professional and defer the updates.

Comment: No only Enterprise has that.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Microsoft's guide  [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/getstarted-choose-how-updates-are-installed)  it tells you that you can defer updates on a metered connection.

Select Settings -> Update & Security -> Windows Update -> Advanced Settings.

You can't disable them completely without the Enterprise version Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Enterprise is the only version you can completely disable windows 10 updates.